# Drupal Access Control List

Tags: drupal-6, sitemap

To make sure my site is secure and all the permissions are set correctly, I am looking for a way to generate a list of every page that a specific user has access to. (So... every menu callback where `user_access()` returns `TRUE` for a given uid).

Something that would look like this:

$user->uid == 0

> Home
>
> Photos
>
> Contact Us

$user->uid = 23

> Home
>
> Photos
>
> Contact Us
>
> Forum
>
> Blog

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really feasible in Drupal, as there are no real *pages* from a System perspective, only callback functions taking arguments. To clarify, think of the standard path for node pages:

```
node/[nid]
```

This will accept an arbitrary integer for [nid] and then the callback function for the `node/%` path will try to find a node with a matching id - it is only *after* looking for it that Drupal 'knows' if the page actually exists.

The same is true for all other paths, so basically you are looking at an (almost) unlimited number of *potential* pages, with no way to know, short of testing the paths, if they actually 'exist' or end in a 404.

What you *could* do is taking a look at the `menu_router` table. There you'll find all the registered paths, along with their callback and access_callback functions. For those you could do the checking per user, but the result would be hard to interpret, as the paths are plenty and will contain many placeholders.

A similar option exists if you use URL-Aliases/pathauto. Then you could take the `url_alias` table and do the check for all the entries in there. But since you are interested in securing your site, this will not really help, as you would miss any path that does not have an alias - and as said above, these are countless.

Comment: Ok. What if I just wanted a list of accessible nodes?

Comment: Check the `node_access()` function. You could loop over all your nodes and check the result of `node_access($op, $node, $account)` for the possible values of $op (view, update, create, delete) for the users ($account) you're interested in. Certainly doable, but still quite some processing, given enough nodes and users ...